# Adding Data to Biometric Device C#

Tags: c#

I have a Biometric Device from ZKTeco Company. Through my C# Code i can successfully connect to the device, Ping it etc.
There is a function in the supported SDK "SSR_SetUserInfo" which returns a Boolean Value and there is a button on the form "btn_WriteData_Click" the purpose of code written for this button is to write data in the device. I have stored the boolean value returned by clicking this button in a variable "result" and added code for successful write operation which is a MessageBox which displays "Result Stored in the Device" in Case returned Boolean value is "True" or otherwise (as shown below). When i click this button i get the message "Result Stored in the Device" so i believe data has been stored in the device. I also made similar changes to the code of button "btn_ReadData_Click"(as shown below) and found similar results so i believe read operation is also a success.
Now, i need to display data on the form when the second button "btn_ReadData_Click" is clicked. Can you guide me what should i add in the code of "btn_ReadData_Click"?

```
private void btn_WriteData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int MachineNumber = 1;
string EnrollNumber = "1";
string Name = "Mich";
string Password = "123";
int Privilege = 1;
bool Enabled = true;
bool result = objZkeeper.SSR_SetUserInfo(MachineNumber, EnrollNumber, Name, Password, Privilege, Enabled);
if (result == true)
{
MessageBox.Show("Result Stored in the Device");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Result Not Stored in the Device");
}    
}

private void btn_ReadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
int MachineNumber = 1;
string EnrollNumber = "1";
string Name = "";
string Password = "";
int Privilege = 0;
bool Enabled = true;
bool result = objZkeeper.SSR_GetUserInfo(MachineNumber, EnrollNumber, out Name, out Password, out Privilege, out Enabled);
if (result == true)
{
MessageBox.Show("Result Retrieved");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Result Not Retrieved");
}
}
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.
Best Regards

MS

Comment: "Any help is appreciated" doing what? You forgot to explain the problem / ask the question

Comment: just in a general sense your SSR_SetUserInfo and your SSR_GetUserInfo meothds return bool you should probably capture that and check it.  Also in your read data you are passing it a blank Enrollnumber.  Just a wild guess here I would imagine since you are attempting ot access a specific user with that method you would need to pass the matching enroll number so it should be 1.  Keep in mind this is a total guess as I am not familiar with the API at all I just quickly pulled it in via nuget and explored it.